# jQuery selectmenu doubles when assets are precompiled for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

*EDIT: Simplified the `_header.mobile.erb` file because the issue persists even in this simplest form. Added the production environment file*

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0, and have a select menu in my header as below.

**application.mobile.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "mobile" %>
```

**mobile.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js
```

**_header.mobile.erb**

```
  <select>
    <option value="1">Home</option>
    <option value="2">New</option>
    <option value="3">About</option>
  </select>
```

This select menu show up fine in development. However, when I precompile my assets for deployment, I get a double select menu (What should look like a single select menu button now looks like a button within a button).
Note that I have normal buttons (data-role="button"), and these do NOT get doubled.

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.precompile += [ 'custom.css', 'mobile.css', 'jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css', 'mobile.js', 'jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js' ]
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: when you load them, you bind them to which event? `pageinit`, `pageshow`..etc.

Comment: Hi @Omar. I'm not explicitly binding them to any specific event. The code attached is literally all I have. I load them via `<%= javascript_include_tag "mobile" %>` in the head of my application layout.
Do I need to add something to bind them?

Comment: Hmmm..it could be a ruby problem not JQM.